# What is the Negation Normal Form of ¬(¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm working with the book "Language, Proof and Logic" and they asked me to make an NNF of this sentence ¬(¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C).
They said that the resulting Sentence **won't have any negation signs** in it.

Did I make a mistake when translating it from

¬(¬Cube(a) ∨ ¬Larger(a, b) ∨ a ≠ b) to ¬(¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)?

and why is

(A ∨ B ∨ ¬C) wrong?

Comment: $\lnot (\lnot A \vee \lnot B \vee C)$  is the same as $(A \wedge B \wedge \lnot C)$ rather than $(A \vee B \vee \lnot C)$

Comment: @Henry thanks, helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the formula $\neg (\neg A \vee \neg B \vee C)$ in [Negation Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form) as follows:

$\neg (\neg A \vee \neg B \vee C)$

$\neg \neg A \wedge \neg \neg B \wedge \neg C \:\:\:\:\:\:$ by [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

$A \wedge B \wedge \neg C \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ by [double negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#:%7E:text=Double%20negation%20elimination%20and%20double,negation%20from%20a%20formal%20proof.) elimination

**NOTE**: if $C$ is "$a \neq b$," then $\neg C$ is "$\neg(a \neq b)$" which is logically equivalent to "$\neg \neg (a=b)"$ and "$a=b$."

Answer (score 0):

You made two, and possibly three, mistakes.

First, $a\neq b$ is short for $\neg a=b$. So, the sentence is really of the form $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B \lor \color{red}\neg C)$

Second, when applying DeMorgan’s laws, make sure to change the $\lor$ into $\land$ (and vice versa). So, what you get is $A \color{red}\land B \color{red}\land C$

Note: there are indeed no negations in this sentence (and it is in NNF)

Finally, I am not so sure that they want $A \land B \land C$ as your answer …. Wouldn’t they want you to work with the original predicates? In which case the answer would be $Cube(a) \land Larger(a,b) \land a =b$